# SQL Server to EXCEL number format

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I'm trying to export data from SQL Server to EXCEL. I have a table which has a column type is number format. This column holds over 18 digits of number. Excel converts last 2 digits of number to "0" and to (9,30102E+16) this format.

http://www.ufuktukenmez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dddddd.png

I need to export to data to excel same as in sql format.

Also need to be shown all number in Excel.

EXCEL format: `9,30102E+16` , when clicked on the number value is `93010241000000000`
SQL format:   `93010241000000011`

Answer (score 0):

Excel (2010) supports a precision of 15 digits only.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx#BMcalculation

As far as I see it, you can only choose between that and saving your number as text.

Comment: How do you accomplish this though? I had to add SELECT '''' + COLUMN_NAME + '''' to my query. Even doing so, when I opened it in Excel, explicitly formatted the cell to make it of type Text instead of the default General and then did a find and replace to remove the single quotes, excel still reformatted the column automatically to a number and truncated its value. Any way around this?

Comment: Hm, it should always work with a leading single quote (just remove the quote after the <column>). This forces Excel to treat a value as text, the single quote should not be visible (only when editing the cell).